# Combine 2 math font together

Tags: fonts

I want to use `pxfonts` package as the main math font in my document.

But I also need `fourier` package to use `\wideOarc` command.

Is there any solution to combine those math fonts? Thank a lot :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
$\wideOarc{AB}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `\wideOarc` accessible (all needed information is in `fourier.sty`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideOarc}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{228}

\begin{document}
$\wideOarc{AB}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A brief description (for details, refer to `fntguide.pdf` available using `texdoc fntguide.pdf` in a terminal).

```
\DeclareMathAccent{<cmd>}{<type>}{<sym-font>}{<slot>}
```

Defines `<cmd>` to act as a math accent. The accent character comes from slot `<slot>` in `<sym-font>`. The `<type>` can be either `\mathord` or `\mathalpha`; in the latter case the accent character changes font when used in a math alphabet.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{<sym-font>}{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

A new symbol font with this name is created. The arguments `<encoding>`, `<family>`, `<series>` and `<shape>` are used to set, or reset the default values for this symbol font in all math versions.
command.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what i desired :) But I cannot understand those command means :(