# Incompatibilities between fourier and other mathfont

Tags: fonts

When I combine fourier and other mathfont, there are some symbols not dislayed correctly. The operator "+" disappeared and the \left( \right) doesn't word. Is there any solution that I still can use those math fonts together. Thank you :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
Pxfonts along with fourier: $\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{z+x}} \right)^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine these two fonts?  Are you aware of `newpxmath` and `newpxtext`?

Comment: Sorry, but it makes no sense loading `pxfonts` after `fourier`: at best you get Utopia as text font and a Palatino based math font, which are visually clashing.

Comment: how does this relate to your other question, [Combine 2 math font together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253729/579)?  there, you wanted `fourier` only for `\wideOarc`, and the technique for using only one or two symbols from that (or any different) font was correctly provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get what you want, but I heartily discourage you from doing so.

The `fourier` package uses different font encodings for the math fonts, that it sets up at begin document, so after `pxfonts` has performed its duties: of course this utterly confuses math typesetting, because symbols will point to very different slots than expected by `pxfonts`.

The `fourier` package part related to text fonts is very easy and it boils down to

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs} % Utopia as text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
```

Full example; note that the instruction for setting Utopia as text font must come after `\usepackage{pxfonts}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs}

\begin{document}

Pxfonts along with fourier: $\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{z+x}} \right)^2$

Compare \textit{x} and $x$ or \textit{z} and $z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

My bet is that you just want Palatino for everything; then prefer `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}

Pxfonts along with fourier: $\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{z+x}} \right)^2$

Compare \textit{x} and $x$ or \textit{z} and $z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left the same text even if it states a falsity.

Note that in either case you shouldn't load `amssymb` and `amsfonts` (the former loads automatically the latter, by the way). You should *never* load `latexsym` that's only provided for compatibility with older documents.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to use fourier just because its \wideOarc :)

Comment: @minmin I suspected that the question was of the [XY type](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). See also [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386). If you are not able to import `\wideOarc`, please ask a question about it.