# Fourier package causes equation to not show up properly

Tags: equations, fourier

In the MWE below, I do not get the equation to show up properly.  This is how it shows up:
[image]

when this is the equation:

```
E(T) = C_{1} + C_{2}f_{1}[p(t)] + C_{3}f_{2}[T(t)] + C_{4}f_{3}[p(t),T(t)] + v(t)
```

I did the updmap.exe and also ran  the "REFRESH FNDB" in MiKTeX for Windows but still did not get the equation to show up properly.  I am using the Fourier package because it is being used in the chapter title headings.  Can the Fourier package work here in conjunction with the equations showing up correctely?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, ltablex, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Problem 2.4}\index{Problem 2.4}

(Mendel, 1973, Exercise 1-17, pp. 46-47).  The efficiency of a jet engine may be viewed as a linear combination of functions of inlet pressure $p(t)$ and the operating temperature $T(t)$; i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
E(T) = C_{1} + C_{2}f_{1}[p(t)] + C_{3}f_{2}[T(t)] + C_{4}f_{3}[p(t),T(t)] + v(t)
\end{equation*}
where the structures of $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$, and $f_{3}$ are known a priori and $v(t)$ represents modeling error of known mean and variance.  From tests on the engine a table of values of $E(t)$, $p(t)$, and $T(t)$ is given at discrete values of $t$.  Explain how $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$, $C_{3}$, and $C_{4}$ are estimated from these data.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Loading both `fourier` and `mathptmx` is wrong: they fight against each other for defining math fonts. Just load one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either want `fourier` (in order to get the document in Utopia) or `mathptmx` (so the font will be Times Roman). Not both: see [Incompatibilities between fourier and other mathfont](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253747/incompatibilities-between-fourier-and-other-mathfont) for another similar situation.

Loading both packages will result in a disaster, because `fourier` uses non standard math font encodings, which are set at `\begin{document}`, so many symbol commands will point to the wrong position in the font.

Other font packages with an accompanying math font may be loaded together and the last one prevails, but it's better having just one. The reverse order (first `mathptmx`, then `fourier`) is good, but the first package will do nothing, so it's better not to load it to begin with.

Instead of `mathptmx` you can consider

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

because you have a richer supply of symbols (bold symbols, for instance).

Comment: I tried your '\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` and ran through the exercise of installing the newtx fonts, and then did a "REFRESH FNDB" and also a update.exe but I got the error `Couldn't find 't1x.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font t1xtt. ! Font T1/ntxtt/m/n/10=t1xtt at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.` Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: @Joe I'd suggest a full install of MiKTeX.

Comment: The same is of course true for `fouriernc`