# Problem redefining hat accent in eulerpx

Tags: accents, parentheses, eulervm

I want to use `eulerpx` with the alternative hat accent provided by `eulervm` (via the `euler-hat-accent` option). To this end, I copied the relevant commands from `eulervm.sty` (see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253731/32352)). The problem is that the redefinition messes with parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,newpxtext,eulerpx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{U}{zeus}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{symbols}{222}

\begin{document}

$\hat{a}\qquad(b)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the redefinition of the hat accent (`DeclareSymbolFont,DeclareMathAccent`) the output is as expected: no omitted parentheses and no extra colon, but of course the modified hat is not obtained.

[image]

Am I redefining the hat accent in a wrong way? Is there a way to avoid this strange behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first command `\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{U}{zeus}{m}{n}` defines the math symbol family `symbols`, but eulerpx already defines a symbol family with this name, so you overwrite it. But this is the family where the parentheses come from, so they are replaced with the symbols the new `symbols` font provides in the respective positions, for example the colon. You can fix this by choosing another name for the family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,newpxtext,eulerpx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{zeussymbols}{U}{zeus}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{zeussymbols}{222}

\begin{document}

$\hat{a}\qquad(b)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Relatedly, the closest equivalent of `eulerpx` in the modern toolchain is to `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}` with Palatino or a clone such as Pagella as the Roman font, optionally Optima or a clone such as Classico as the sans-serif font, a `newpx` clone such as Asana as the main math font, and then portions of Neo Euler.

The following loads all the combining accents from Neo Euler in math mode:

```
\setmathfont[Scale = MatchLowercase,
             range={up,bfup,cal,bfcal,frak,bffrak,
                    "0301-"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"033B}
            ]{euler.otf}
```